# C++ dynamic_cast vs storing object type in a static enum?

Tags: c++, object, types, casting, dynamic-cast

I am developing a big hierarchy of classes for a framework that will require quite a lot of type casting when it gets done.

My question is, how stupid of an idea is to put in a static member that uses an enum to store all the object types in the hierarchy. Having the member static for every class will not increase the instanced object sizes, and will give a (potentially) faster way to determined the type of an object during runtime than dynamic_cast.

At least that's the basic idea. How adequate would this approach be, and are there any potential flaws?

Comment: There's one potential flaw. This idea cannot possibly work. Try it with an hierarchy of 2 classes and see.

Comment: Yes, the flaw is that to get the correct static member you must first know the object's type.

Comment: If you don't plan to access the static member with a virtual function, that is. If you do, then this becomes just another home-grown, inefficient, un-idiomatic, unmaintainable, redundant implementation of RTTI. Get one that the compiler gives you, it's already there and it's virtually (pun intended) free.

Comment: a hierarchy of classes that requires a lot of casting is flawn. Perhaps you can fix your design with double dispatch or function objects.

Comment: Why do you require a lot of casting?  If you have to cast to a type to get some functionality, then it's not `polymorphic`, and if it's not `polymorphic` then why do you want to model it as such?

Comment: "that will require quite a lot of type casting when it gets done." Then your design is bad and you should start over.

Comment: Agree with Nicol. Would recommend that the OP pick up a copy of [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612)

Comment: I see the flaw in my concept, sorry it was a stupid question, I must admit. Now I know better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you were gonna determine the type of each object from a static variable that is shared between the objects. Unless you have some virtual function that you override for each class, but then you don't need the static variable at all, just do something like this:

```
struct Base
{
   virtual int type() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
   virtual int type() { return 1; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
   virtual int type() { return 2; }
};
```

Not the fastest solution, but several magnitudes faster than `dynamic_cast` or `typeid`.

Comment: This exactly answers the question, but still leaves the question as to what the OP is trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly better and different answer. I didn't wanted to change Timo's answer so submitted a new one. Rationale behind this is to avoid magic numbers. Sometimes typecasting and fiddling with objects is necessary to add new functionality when the aim is not to modify the original classes. But this should not allow someone to use magic numbers.

```
enum mytypeid {
    DERIVED1,
    DERIVED2,
};

struct Base
{
   virtual mytypeid type() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
   static const mytypeid mytype = DERIVED1;

   virtual mytypeid type() { return mytype ; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
   static const mytypeid mytype = DERIVED2;

   virtual mytypeid type() { return mytype ; }
};

//...

void fn(Base &a) {
     if(a.type() == Derived1::mytype) {
        std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
     }
}
```