# dynamic_cast vs virtual function vs member enum?

Tags: c++

My question refers to:

[C++ dynamic_cast vs storing object type in a static enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216398/c-dynamic-cast-vs-storing-object-type-in-a-static-enum)

where the question has been left unanswered. `dynamic_cast` requires `RTTI`, whereas virtual functions require a table lookup, slowing down their invocations (I know Stroustrup recommends this). Is an enum + an accessor the fastest way to discern between types?

EDIT:

The point of my post was a class `Screen`:

```
class ScreenImpl;

class Screen
{
public:
  enum Type
  {
    GLES1,
    GLES2,
    GLES3
  };

  enum Type type() const noexcept { return type_; }

private:
  enum Type type_;

  ScreenImpl* impl_;
};
```

The class can have different implementations (using `PIMPL`, one of 3 different contexts can be created, the header file stays the same, so a `static_cast` is ok) and I thought objects might query under what context they are running (GLES1, GLES2 or GLES3). Alternatively, I could have used a `dynamic_cast` (needs at least 1 virtual member function) or `typeid`. Now, after reading the posts I think I will do away with this and have all objects know under what context they are running in advance (foregoing all ifs and switches, as well as invocations of virtual functions).

Comment: Is it me or you are trying to reinvent `typeid` operator? What are you trying to achieve? Do you need polymorphism and if so, do you need dynamic or static polymorphism?

Comment: Since all three techniques are doing roughly the same logic, it's unlikely that any of them will be significantly faster than the others.  What really makes one approach better than another here is how it succeeds (or fails) in keeping your program's code manageable and extensible over time.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish? If it's something along the lines of "I want something like a virtual method, but I think I can be smarter than the compiler", then stop right there. Maybe you can, but it's almost certainly not worth the effort and conceptual load.

Comment: and how are you going to implement the "accessor"? with a table lookup? :) As the linked answers mentioned, `static` really doesn't make sense, as it's not dynamic. you have to store the type in each *object*...

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: So correct! Manageable and clear code are the number one considerations in practice.

Comment: @PetrBudnik static polymorphism means templates and templates mean lots of generated code?

Comment: @user1095108 It _might_ mean more code generated. But it also means type safety (no `std::bad_cast` at run-time), faster code (no indirections), and smaller memory footprint (in terms of data size - each `vptr` is 8 bytes on `x64`).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath a `static_cast` would suffice for the use case.

Comment: @user1095108: for accessing a `static` member polymorphically? I don't see how...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I've overlooked, that my member was/is not static, see the example. Fixed now.

Comment: @user1095108: adding completely new approach which invalidates my comment then replying to it... that's just wrong, mate...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm sorry, the other guy did not provide any code at all and it's late.

Comment: "have all objects know under what context they are running in advance" - this smells like a bit like the state/strategy design pattern, though to be honest I still don't know what are you doing and why...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The contexts are OpenGL ES (GLES) contexts. In theory, it is possible to write code, that works under contexts of different OpenGL ES versions, though such code is probably rare. The strategy pattern would probably be an overkill, but it is an interesting thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly often, you need all three... ;)

In general, the slow-down of virtual is less than the overhead of `if (x) do_something`. In particular if you get more than one if-statement, it will be very detrimental to performance. In other words, storing an enum in each class is going to be at least as bad as calling a virtual function, when it comes to performance.

[And like the answer in the previous question says, you can't have a single static enum, unless ALL objects are the same type, and in that case, you are not talking about something where you should be using virtual anyway].

In most compilers, `dynamic_cast` just requires a vtable - the compiler will produce code to compare the address of the `vtable` with the known type. But if you believe that comparing the vtable + comparing that the result is not NULL is better (performance wise, obviously design could be a different matter) than calling a virtual function, I think you'll find that you're wrong.

If you have performance issues because you are using virtual functions, then perhaps the objects themselves are badly designed/incorrectly used, or something. For example, perhaps calling a virtual function PER PIXEL is a bad idea, and you should use a function that operates on a region of pixels...

Of course, as always, with anything dealing with performance, you need to measure on your system, with your compiler and your compiler settings (don't measure on a debug build tho' - compiler often does pessimisations that aren't representative for "real code" when you have NO optimisation on).

Note also that compilers can (sometimes) devirtualise functions. There is more work in progress so that the compiler will do this "better". See for example Jan Hubicka's posts on the subject here:
http://hubicka.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html

Answer (score 6):

When in doubt, profile and check assembly :)

Here is a comparison of the three cases (with a `dynamic_cast`, with a virtual fuction (`type`) and with an `enum`). For the sake of simplicity, the `special` method is the same in all cases to only see the difference in real cases. However, in a real world setting, "special" would be something different each time, else there would be no point.

The `by_enum` also provides a demonstration of what happens in a vcall at the beginning.

```
enum Type { D1_t, D2_t, D3_t, D4_t, D5_t };
struct Base
{
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual Type type() = 0;
};

struct D1 : public Base
{ 
  Type type() override { return D1_t; }
  int special1();
};
struct D2 : public Base{ 
  Type type() override { return D2_t; } 
  int special2();
};
struct D3 : public D2{
  Type type() override { return D3_t; } 
  int special3();
};
struct D4 : public D2{ 
  Type type() override { return D4_t; }
  int special4();
};
struct D5 : public D4{
  Type type() override { return D5_t; }
  int special5();
};


int by_dynamic(Base* b)
{
  if(auto d = dynamic_cast<D1*>(b)) return d->special1();
  else if(auto d = dynamic_cast<D2*>(b)) return d->special2();
  else if(auto d = dynamic_cast<D3*>(b)) return d->special3();
  else if(auto d = dynamic_cast<D4*>(b)) return d->special4();
  else if(auto d = dynamic_cast<D5*>(b)) return d->special5();
}

int by_enum(Base* b)
{
  switch(b->type())
  {
    case D1_t:
      return static_cast<D1*>(b)->special1();
      break;
    case D2_t:
      return static_cast<D2*>(b)->special2();
      break;
    case D3_t:
      return static_cast<D3*>(b)->special3();
      break;
    case D4_t:
      return static_cast<D4*>(b)->special4();
      break;
    case D5_t:
      return static_cast<D5*>(b)->special5();
      break;
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant ASM for `by_dynamic` (GCC-5.2, `-O3`). So I'd argue that if you're performance-constrained, go for the enum.

```
by_dynamic(Base*):
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    je  .L15
    pushq   %rbx
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    typeinfo for D1, %edx
    movl    typeinfo for Base, %esi
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    call    __dynamic_cast
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L3
    popq    %rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    jmp D1::special1()
.L3:
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    typeinfo for D2, %edx
    movl    typeinfo for Base, %esi
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    call    __dynamic_cast
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L4
    popq    %rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    jmp D2::special2()
.L4:
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    typeinfo for D3, %edx
    movl    typeinfo for Base, %esi
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    call    __dynamic_cast
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L5
    popq    %rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    jmp D3::special3()
.L5:
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    typeinfo for D4, %edx
    movl    typeinfo for Base, %esi
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    call    __dynamic_cast
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L6
    popq    %rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    jmp D4::special4()
.L6:
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    typeinfo for D5, %edx
    movl    typeinfo for Base, %esi
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    call    __dynamic_cast
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L2
    popq    %rbx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    jmp D5::special5()
.L2:
    popq    %rbx
.L15:
    ret
```

And for `by_enum`

```
by_enum(Base*):
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    call    *16(%rax)
    cmpl    $4, %eax
    ja  .L18
    movl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    jmp *.L20(,%rax,8)
.L20:
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L21
    .quad   .L22
    .quad   .L23
    .quad   .L24
    popq    %rbx
    jmp D4::special4()
    popq    %rbx
    jmp D5::special5()
    popq    %rbx
    jmp D1::special1()
    popq    %rbx
    jmp D2::special2()
    popq    %rbx
    jmp D3::special3()
.L18:
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```

Answer (score 3):

Vtable 'lookup' is valuing of the offset (one plus operation) and then dereferencing a pointer to the function.
Static enum will cost several 'if' checks. If there are a lot of ifs, it can cost more :) But you should measure such things. 
Compile-time template polymorphism will cost you nothing at run time.

Comment: Dont forget that RTTI lookup is much more complex than vftable lookup. Also notice that compiler can optimize switch statements to have O(1) complexity (multiplication+jump), so your statement about enums isnt that right.

Answer (score 1):

Quick [benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/hF5wNrQ2t7qykPGpY1pm5vZeXd0) shows that members are the best.
[image]

If you already have virtual methods, it's better to add another one, than increase size of every class with enum member (I think).

`dynamic_cast` is awfully slow even for a simple case with 2 classes